# Auth0 in combination with Shiny app does not work when calling URL from shinyapps.io

Tags: auth0, shinyapps

I have used the standard ShinyApp (Old faithful Geyser Data) and added the Auth0 layer as described by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vq32tbqFdiM

I have deployed the app including the yml file at the shinyapps.io site
When I run the app from my laptop I do get the authorization screen and get access after providing the password.
However when I use the URL from the shinyapps.io I get the following message: "Site is not available"

Don't know what is going wrong because I added all the required call-back URL's.

In my Auth0 account I have added the following URL's (for allowed callback, logout, and weborigins):

https://my_projectname.shinyapps.io/Test_auth0, http://localhost:8080

I have tried changing the URL: https in http. Also I deployed the .Renviron file on the shinyapps.io server but nothing helped.

I believe I have forgotten something simple but cannot figure out what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Best regards,

Coen